# Transforming coordinates system to obtain an ellipse in the standard form

Tags: geometry, transformation

Let $E$ be the ellipse $x^2+xy +y^2 = 1$. I would like to obtain the area of $E$ with the formula $ab\pi$. I am not able to transform the equation in the form $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. The textbook I am following uses a transformation to describe $E$ as $$\dfrac{X^2}{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}+\dfrac{Y^2}{1^2}=1$$

I do not understand what intermediate steps lead to this transformation.

EDIT : As some were curious, this is the original question:

Use Stoke's Theorem to to evaluate $\oint_C\vec{F}\cdot\vec{dr}$. Assume C is oriented counterclockwise as viewed from above.

$$\vec{F} = z\vec{i}+x\vec{j} + y\vec{k}$$

$C$ is the curve of intersection of the plane $x + y + z = 0$ and the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

Hint : recall that the area of an ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is $ab\pi$

The textbook solution : 3 * Area of R = $3 \cdot \dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt(3)}$=$\sqrt3\pi$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341632/transform-curve-into-canonical-form-and-determine-type
 that should help you

Comment: This transformation does not preserve area. If you want an area-preserving transformation, you should rotate coordinates $45^\circ$ and in the new coordinates you will have the ellipse $$\frac{X^2}{2} + \frac{Y^2}{2/3} = 1.$$

Comment: Another area-preserving transformation is $x=X,$ $y=Y-X/2.$

Comment: So now I'm curious exactly what transformation the book chose to use and why. The parts you didn't show us presumably answer "what" and probably give some clues to "why".

Comment: I added the original question to add extra context as it could perhaps help answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\dfrac x2$ and $Y=\dfrac x2  + y$.

Then $\dfrac{X^2}{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}+\dfrac{Y^2}{1^2}=3X^2+Y^2=\dfrac34x^2+\dfrac14x^2+xy+y^2=1$.

**Addendum:**

The above explains the intermediate steps that led to the transformation, as the original post requested, but it should be noted, as alluded to in the comments, that the transformation

$\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12 & 0 \\ \frac12 &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $\frac12$, so this transformation halves area, and that must be taken into account when addressing the underlying question about the area of the ellipse.

Comment: How to come up with these transformations?

Comment: You could also get $X^2+Y^2=\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2$ with $X=\dfrac{x+y}2$ and $Y=\dfrac{x-y}2$

Comment: How I came up with this:  I figured that $X=ax+by$ and $Y=cx+y,$ and I solved $3X^2+Y^2=1$ to see that $a=0, 2c=1, $ and $3a^2+c^2=1$

Comment: Watch out. This change of coordinates is not a rotation and is not area-preserving.

Comment: @AmerYR: You can do it by completing the square: $y^2 + xy = (y+\tfrac12 x)^2 - (\tfrac12 x)^2$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: The square is missing on $y^2$ in the very last step.

Comment: @HansLundmark:  thank you for pointing out the typographical error.  I have edited to insert the missing superscript $2$

Comment: But your transformation does not have determinant equal to $1$.

Comment: @Lubin:  I was merely answering the original post, asking for "what  intermediate steps lead to this transformation" from $x^2+xy+y=1$ to $3X^2+Y^2=1$; yes, as others have pointed out, this transformation does not preserve area; the determinant is $\frac12,$ and that must be accounted for when calculating area

Comment: Right, @J.W.Tanner. I think it would have been helpful to OP to point this out when you did your answer up.

Comment: Ok, @Lubin, I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The better solution of your original problem is indeed to apply Stokes's Theorem on the original curve. Take the filled in disk bounded by the circle $C$ *in the plane* $x+y+z=0$. When you compute $\text{curl}\,\vec F\cdot\vec n$, you will get a constant. Then multiply this constant by the area of the *circle* (easy enough, since it's a circle of radius $1$).

**EDIT**: The textbook answer is correct, but their “derivation” is highly suspect.

Answer (score 1):

This ellipse contains the six points $(\pm1,0)$, $(0,\pm1)$, $(-1,1)$, and $(1,-1)$. It’s symmetric about both diagonals through the origin.

Thus the diagonal $y=-x$ is the major axis, and $y=x$ is the minor axis; the endpoints of the major axis are $(-1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$, so that the semimajor axis is of length $\sqrt2$, while the endpoints of the minor axis are $\pm(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3})$, the semiminor axis thus being of length $\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$.

Thus I make the area to be $$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}\,,$$ while your text seems to be claiming that the area is $\pi/\sqrt3$.

Comment: Yes, the textbook claims that the area in the region is $\pi/sqrt(3)$

Comment: Right. I’m sure this won’t be the first time you find an annoying error in a text.

Comment: You can see that the area of the ellipse is greater than that of the square with vertices $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$, which is $2$, so if the textbook says the area is $\pi/\sqrt3$, which is less than $2$, that's wrong

Comment: Yes, @J.W.Tanner, this shows the advantage of looking at the geometry. As it happens, I was already familiar with this ellipse, and its reflection in either axis, $x^2-xy+y^2=1$, in connection with a bit of recreational mathematics I occasionally divert myself with.